# Dynamically add id's to input fields

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, rows

How can I add an id dynamically to each field inside of the table when I click on add? For example, the first row that always shows up would be checkbox0, input0, select0, and the ids of the next row when the add button is clicked would be checkbox1, input1, select1, etc.

Below is my code:

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
  function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    alert("rowCount " +rowCount);
    alert("row " +row);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
      //alert(newcell.childNodes);
      switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "text":
          newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
          break;
        case "checkbox":
          newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
          break;
        case "select-one":
          newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          break;
     }
   }
 }

  </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

   <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <TR>
 <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
<TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
<TD>
 <SELECT name="country">
 <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
<OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
 </SELECT>
</TD>
   </TR>
   </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could do the trick

```
 switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
    case "text":
      newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
      newcell.childNodes[0].id = "input" + rowCount;
      break;
    case "checkbox":
      newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
      newcell.childNodes[0].id = "checkbox" + rowCount;      
      break;
    case "select-one":
      newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      newcell.childNodes[0].id = "select" + rowCount;       
      break;
 }
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tcCAG/1/)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @bfavaretto, you'll need to remove leading white spaces on `select` cell

```
<TD><SELECT name="country">
    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
</TD>
```

Comment: Note: the `<select>` will actually be at `childNodes[1]` because of the whitespace between `<td>` and `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

Even knowing that you didn't say that you can use jQuery, I'm posting an solution with it. Take a look.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $tableBody = $( "#tableBody" );

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var $row = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    var $textInput = $( "<input type='text' id='text_" + i + "'/>" );
    var $checkbox = $( "<input type='checkbox' id='check_" + i + "'/><span> Checkbox " + i + "</span>" );
    $row.append( $( "<td></td>" ).append( $textInput ) );
    $row.append( $( "<td></td>" ).append( $checkbox ) );
    $tableBody.append( $row );
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/C8CRW/

Comment: If I wanted to add two radio buttons to each row would it be $row.append( $( "<td></td>" ).append( $radio), $radio));
so that one radio button could be a yes column and the other a no column

Comment: Try this: var $cell = $( "<td></td>" ); $cell.append( $radio1 ); $cell.append( $radio2 ); $row.append( $cell );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function setIds() {
        var id = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].type == "text") {
                document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].id = "text_" + id;
                id++;
            }

        }
    }
```

And add it at the end of your first function.